# Игнорируется if в C#

Tags: c#, if

Писал одну программку для себя.Там идёт примерно такая строка :

```
код  
if (n != 1);  
 {  
 *код,который должен выполнятся,если n не равно 1*  
 }  
конец кода
```

Но в итоге if игнорируется и тот код,который должен работать при n != 1 работает   всегда,не завсисимо от значения n.
[image: пробовал по разному]

Comment: точку с запятой уберите.

Comment: А на точку с запятой наведите указатель, и почитайте что там написано.

Comment: покажите весь код , все должно работать

Comment: "Возможно,ошибочно пустой оператор"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код эквивалентен следующему:

```
if (n != 1) {};  

*код,который должен выполнятся,если n не равно 1*
```

Нужно убрать `;` в строке условия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Помогло,спасибо